# How to check the installation date of a kernel in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have been asked to check the installation date of a kernel which is already installed in my Linux server. Is there a way to check when the kernel would have got installed in Linux server  ?

Comment: Maybe look at the `vmlinuz` creation date in your `/boot` folder (as it seems to be the file holding the Linux kernel) ?

Comment: Which Linux flavor? Some package managers store installation time, others don't.

Comment: Wrong forum, not a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check kernel installation date:

`#rpm -qa --last | grep kernel`

```
kernel-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64                  Thu Feb 12 00:40:00 2015
```

For more info about kernel package:

```
# rpm -qi setup

Name        : setup                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.8.14                            Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
Release     : 20.el6_4.1                    Build Date: Tue Aug 20 04:24:24 2013
Install Date: Thu Feb 12 00:11:15 2015         Build Host: ppc-007.build.bos.redhat.com
Group       : System Environment/Base       Source RPM: setup-2.8.14-20.el6_4.1.src.rpm
Size        : 666477                           License: Public Domain
Signature   : RSA/8, Thu Sep 12 06:27:42 2013, Key ID 199e2f91fd431d51
Packager    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla>
URL         : https://fedorahosted.org/setup/
Summary     : A set of system configuration and setup files
Description :
The setup package contains a set of important system configuration and
setup files, such as passwd, group, and profile.
```

Comment: I executed rpm -qa --last | grep kernel ... and I got the expected output. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and execute:

```
uname -a
```

And you will get something like:

```
Linux 'user' 3.16.0.-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 18:00:35 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

As you can see, the installation date is shown above.

Comment: That's when the kernel was compiled, not when it was installed.

Comment: Well, you can also install https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

Comment: I echo the same with duskwuff's statement. Running uname -a will give the kernel compilation date not the installation date.

Comment: Thank you for your useful echo comment from a closed post of almost 3 years ago ITInfra.